# replacing an app that uses 15 or more spreadsheets as input

Tags: validation, content-management-system, data-transfer, data-entry

I am struggling with a VB.Net desktop app that some developer wrote 5 or 6 years ago. The data entry team inputs data into multiple spreadsheets (and multiple tabs per excel spreadsheet). The VB.Net desktop app takes around 10 to 15 spreadsheets as input and then validates the data in the excel spreadsheets...

This vb.net code references columns/cells in the spreadsheet, validates data and finally writes the data to a database. I would someday want us to replace this app with a web based data entry tool. Is there a shorter term approach to replacing the VB.Net app? A shorter term approach would invlove creating content, validating content and then writing it into a database...

thanks so much..the vb.net app is brutal and i need some great ideas....

Answer (score 0):

Step 1. 
Identify and remove the validation logic from the VB.NET code

Step 2.
Put the validation logic into a [service layer](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/serviceLayer.html), call the service layer from the VB.NET front-end

Step 3.
Build a website that captures the necessary data and calls the service layer created in Step 2.

Step 4
Retire the VB.NET front-end - celebrate

Comment: the app uses a lot of in-line sql and the validation logic is all over the place....refactoring might be very cumbersome...

Comment: I feel your pain... Doing the work in small phases would allow the current UI to be used in the short-term and might be easier than doing a complete re-write...